# Create Object from txt file without hard coding every object

Tags: java, object, constructor, hashmap, unmarshalling

I'm working on a problem in which I have a txt file that I need to convert into Objects. The format of my file is:

Alabama::Montgomery::205764::155.4

The state name and capital are going being loaded into a hashmap as <String, Object>. I've successfully loaded the Hashmap, but now I need to create each individual Capital Object. Wondering if there is a way to do this without hardcoding every Capital Object. Maybe a loop? Not sure how I go about naming them without hardcoding it.

here is my main method so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MoreStateCapitals.txt")));
    Map<String, Object> stateCapitals = new HashMap<>();
    
    while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = fileReader.nextLine().split("::");
        stateCapitals.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
    }
    
    Set<String> states = stateCapitals.keySet();
    Collection<Object> capitals = stateCapitals.values();
    
    
}
```

and here is my Capital Class, with getters, setters, and Constructor

```
    
    private String name;
    private int population;
    private double squareMileage;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }
    
    public void setPopulation(int population){
        this.population = population;
    }

    public double getSquareMileage() {
        return squareMileage;
    }
    
    public void setSquareMileage(double squareMileage){
        this.squareMileage = squareMileage;
    }

    public Capital(String name, int population, double squareMileage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.squareMileage = squareMileage;
    }
    
}
```

Edit: the only thing the first value from the txt file is used for is the key in the hashmap, it is not involved in the creation of the object

Comment: Your `Capital` object has a constructor, which you should invoke in the loop for each line. Did you write the code or just download it from somewhere?  If you actually wrote it, I'm not sure what the question is.  If you didn't write the code, then your question is off-topic here.  StackOverflow is not a forum, tutorial or code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe that you need to change the line:

```
stateCapitals.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
```

into

```
stateCapitals.put(columns[0], new Capital(columns[1], Integer.parseInt(columns[2]), Double.parseDouble(columns[3]));
```

This way you will be using your constructor to create the object. This assumes that there are no errors in the file from where you read the data - if the file is not OK, you may need to analyze the lines before the creation/insertion step.

Besides, even though your `Collection` of `Object` will work, you may want to change it into a `Collection<Capitals>` to be able to access all methods of your class.

I hope it helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work. I was really only using the Collection at the time to iterate through the values of the map to make sure I had them set correctly.